# What Android 6 (marshmallow) change prompted for systemless rooting?

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, systemless-root, safety-net

Since Android 6 , Chain fire used Systemless rooting for installing SU binaries or for rooting purpose in general. 
I was curious to know what changes in operating system prompted for systemless rooting in the first place. Was it just safety net api detecting old rooting methods or was there an Android OS or other api's change ? 
In particular Which enhancement listed [here](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements60) does it get affected with and how ?